# Key missing from JSON response

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb

I have just noticed that the `overView` key in the below JSON has gone missing in the response from the Node JS API that I have built. The moment I imported the JSON file to my cluster, it went missing and was stored in exactly the same way as the response. Although it seems like this is owing to the fact that I'm querying the data using the toArray() method in my API, the fact that the data got imported without the `overView` key is still a mystery and I would like to know why or what triggered this? Also, if possible, I would like to know if there is any way to fetch the response from the API call as an Object rather than an Array?

The JSON that I initially built and uploaded:

```
{
    "overView": {
        "paraOne": [
            "Homeopathy or homoeopathy is a system of alternative medicine.",
            "It was conceived in 1796 by the German physician Samuel Hahnemann.",
            "Its practitioners, called homeopaths, believe that a substance that causes symptoms of a disease in healthy people can cure similar symptoms in sick people; this doctrine is called similia similibus curentur, or like cures like.",
            "Homeopathic preparations are termed remedies and are made using homeopathic dilution.",
            "In this process, the selected substance is repeatedly diluted until the final product is chemically indistinguishable from the diluent.",
            "Often not even a single molecule of the original substance can be expected to remain in the product.",
            "Between each dilution homeopaths may hit and/or shake the product, claiming this makes the diluent remember the original substance after its removal.",
            "Practitioners claim that such preparations, upon oral intake, can treat or cure disease."
        ]
    }
}
```

This is the response and also the format in which the data got stored:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "61e142ae71cc944be6736ac3",
        "paraOne": [
            "Homeopathy or homoeopathy is a system of alternative medicine.",
            "It was conceived in 1796 by the German physician Samuel Hahnemann.",
            "Its practitioners, called homeopaths, believe that a substance that causes symptoms of a disease in healthy people can cure similar symptoms in sick people; this doctrine is called similia similibus curentur, or like cures like.",
            "Homeopathic preparations are termed remedies and are made using homeopathic dilution.",
            "In this process, the selected substance is repeatedly diluted until the final product is chemically indistinguishable from the diluent.",
            "Often not even a single molecule of the original substance can be expected to remain in the product.",
            "Between each dilution homeopaths may hit and/or shake the product, claiming this makes the diluent remember the original substance after its removal.",
            "Practitioners claim that such preparations, upon oral intake, can treat or cure disease."
        ]
    }
]
```

The API code:

```
app.get('/overView', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req);
    client.connect(err => {
        if(err) {
            throw err;
        }
        const collection = client.db('doctor_app').collection('overview');
        collection.find().toArray(function(err, result) {
            console.log(result);
            res.send(result);
            client.close();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I would need to see your create method in order to help you debug why was it stored without the `overView` key. Also, if you want an object (single object) back from mongo you can use the `findOne` method instead. [Find one documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/current/usage-examples/findOne/)

Comment: @HamzaSabljakovic I used the MongoDB compass console to import the data. But, if you tell me where to find the create method, then I would very happily produce that.

Comment: Sorry, I've never used compass console. I thought that you had an endpoint using the [mongo insert one method](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/current/usage-examples/insertOne/).

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell why `overView` would get dropped.  Also, I am not a fan of using the DB to perform formatting operations which is what I suspect you want in order to bring all those sentences together into 1 string.  The same amount data needs to come across and you're only making the DB engine work harder.
That said, here is a little example that will concatenate the sentences with a space in between and even avoid putting in a leading space.

```js
db.foo.aggregate([
    {$project: {text: {$reduce: {
        input: "$paraOne",
        initialValue: "",
        in: {$cond:[ {$eq:["$$value",""]},  // if (i.e. if first time thru)
                     {$concat: ["$$value","$$this"]},  // then 
                     {$concat: ["$$value",' ',"$$this"]}  // else
               ]}
        }}
    }}
]);
```